# Configure OpenSSL Store

Tags: security, openssl

I am trying to implement the OPC UA verification of certificates with OpenSSL in C. Therefore I have multiple certificates which are stored in different directories.
The directories are:

- CertificateTrustListDir: The folder where certificates of trusted CAs are stored.
- CertificateRevocationListDir: The folder where the revocation lists for the trusted CAs are stored.
- IssuersCertificatesDir:  The folder where issuer certificates are stored. Issuer certificates are CA certificates necessary for the verification of the full trust chain of CA certificates in the trust list.
- IssuersRevocationListDir:    The folder where revocation lists for issuer CAs should be stored.

I was looking into [this example](http://fm4dd.com/openssl/certverify.htm) and discovered the function [SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations.html). Unfortunately I can only set the location of the trusted CAs with this method.

Is there a way to tell OpenSSL to use the directories in the supposed way?

Regards,

ckmk14

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure but this is how I have done:

With the [X509_STORE_CTX_init](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/X509_STORE_CTX_init.html) function I can pass a X509_STORE with the trusted certificates (CertificateTrustListDir) and the CRLS (CertificateRevocationListDir + IssuersRevocationListDir). 
The certificates of the IssuersCertificatesDir can be passed as stack with the chain-parameter of the  X509_STORE_CTX_init function.